# Regex needed for variable expansion in python

Tags: python, regex

I am having a variable having a value something like this

```
var = '${home_${path}}'
```

I want a regex which detects `${ any content }` recursively.  That is, first I should match `${home_${path}}` and then `${path}`. I need this to evaluate the variable content by replacing ${..} with its actual content.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be more than one `${}` in a string like `${home} ${path}`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a regular function here instead of a regular expression.  The problem is that pure regular expressions can't match arbitrarily nested recursive patterns.  So, they aren't much use for track matching openers and closers.

Instead, write a function to make a pass over the input string tracking the openers in a LIFO stack (just append to a regular python list) and then match closers as you find them (popping off the most recent corresponding opener):

```
import re

braces = re.compile(r'(\${)|(})')

def substitute(s, **env):
    openers = []
    pos = 0
    while 1:
        mo = braces.search(s, pos)
        if mo is None:
            break
        opener, closer = mo.groups()
        if opener:
            openers.append(mo.start())
            pos = mo.end() + 1
            continue
        start = openers.pop()
        end = mo.end()
        body = s[start+2 : end-1]
        s = s[:start] + env[body] + s[end:]
    return s


print substitute('Return to ${home_${path}} for further ${action}',
                 home_world='earth',
                 home_state='kansas',
                 path='state',
                 action='orders')
```

Comment: Regex can count just fine, to a finite amount. ;-)  If talking about formal regular expressions that is. Regex libs like .NET can *really* count (you can add and subtract with balancing groups).